# i cant send email using php

Tags: php, html

hi guys this is a template i bought inside this template there was a ready made php form for sending and email but it doesn't work could anyone help please .
i tried many way and btw i'm not that much good in php but i need use this php contact

```
contact.html
    <div class="contact-main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                    <div class="box-contact-right-form">
                        <h3>Get In Touch</h3>

                        <form id="contact-form-cont" class="contact-right-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
                            <div class="row clearfix">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <input name="name" id="name-cont" value="" placeholder="Your Name" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <input name="mail" id="mail-cont" value="" placeholder="Email Address" required="" type="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <input name="number" id="number-cont" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <input id="company-cont" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" required="" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment-cont" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <button id="submit_contact-cont" type="submit" name="submit" class="theme-btn btn-style-one button-wayra-a">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this the contact php i checked a lot but i didn't saw any mistake and btw i'm not that much good in php

contact.php

```
    <?php 

        /* ==========================  Define variables ========================== */

        #Your e-mail address
        define("__TO__", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com= From:");

        #Message subject
        define("__SUBJECT__", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com= From:");

        #Success message
        define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Your message has been sent. Thank you!");

        #Error message 
        define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Error, your message hasn't been sent");

        #Messege when one or more fields are empty
        define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__', "Please fill out  all fields");

        /* ========================  End Define variables ======================== */

        //Send mail function
        function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
            if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
            }
        }

        //Check e-mail validation
        function check_email($email){
            if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get post data
        if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['mail']) and isset($_POST['comment'])){
            $name    = $_POST['name'];
            $mail    = $_POST['mail'];
            $number  = $_POST['number'];
            $company  = $_POST['company'];      
            $comment = $_POST['comment'];

            if($name == '') {
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your Name."));
                exit();
            } else if($mail == '' or check_email($mail) == false){
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter valid E-mail."));
                exit();
            } else if($number == ''){
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your Number."));
                exit();
            } else if($company == ''){
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your Company."));
                exit();
            } else if($comment == ''){
                echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your Message."));
                exit();
            } else {
                //Send Mail
                $to = __TO__;
                $subject = __SUBJECT__ . ' ' . $name;
                $message = '
                <html>
                <head>
                  <title>Mail from '. $name .'</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                  <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" border="1">
                    <tr style="height: 32px;">
                      <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Name:</th>
                      <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $name .'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 32px;">
                      <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">E-mail:</th>
                      <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $mail .'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 32px;">
                      <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Website:</th>
                      <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $website .'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="height: 32px;">
                      <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Comment:</th>
                      <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $comment .'</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </body>
                </html>
                ';

                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";

                send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__));
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: This is not your original email ids if I am not wrong. If it is then update it.

Comment: may i ask what you mean

Comment: yes it is btw and i changed it so many  its still not working

Comment: He is telling you, you shouldn't use your emailaddress in example code.. Now we could add it to some spam service to make your inbox explode.

Comment: @KirkBeard The email address has been removed as part of an edit. Can you change your comment as well?

Comment: Sure. I have deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the constants to:

```
#Your e-mail address
define("__TO__", "youraddress@gmail.com");

#Message subject
define("__SUBJECT__", "This is the subject");
```